# Angular Spec unused testing module classes

Tags: angular, typescript, testing, dependency-injection

In angular spec tests, you can use the TestBed configureTestingModule to define imports, declarations, providers and schemas. Is there some way to check whether any of these provided classes are not actually required by the tests itself, and can be safely removed?